# Как правильно настроить FreeRadius + OpenLdap?

Tags: centos, ldap, freeradius

Настраиваю связку FreeRadius + OpenLdap ОС centos7. Задача на данный момент: имеется Mikrotik который должен конектиться к радиусу и выполнять роль dhcp-сервера, ip должен получать из LDAP. На Mikrotik настроил подключение к радиусу и назначил роль dhcp-сервера, в dhcp сервере установил флаг `Use RADIUS`.  В связке с mysql все работает, настроил по [этой](http://yvision.kz/post/635887) статье. Связку с LDAP прописал в данном файле `/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap`.

```
ldap {
      server = "ldap.local"
      port = 389
      identity = "uid=radius,ou=services,dc=server,dc=com"
      password = password
      base_dn = "dc=server,dc=com"
user {
             base_dn = "${..base_dn}"
             filter = "(uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})"
             access_attribute = "uid"
  }
group {
             base_dn = "${..base_dn}"
             filter = "(|(&(objectClass=GroupOfNames)(member=%{Ldap-UserDn}))(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=%{Ldap-UserDn})))"
   }
profile {
             filter = "(objectclass=radiusprofile)"
    }
client {
             base_dn = "${..base_dn}"
attribute {
                     identifier                      = 'radiusClientIdentifier'
                     secret                          = 'radiusClientSecret'
        }
     }
accounting {
             reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}}"
             type {
                     start {
                             update {
                                     description := "Online at %S"
                             }
                     }
                     interim-update {
                             update {
                                     description := "Last seen at %S"
                             }
                     }
                     stop {
                             update {
                                     description := "Offline at %S"
                             }
                     }
             }
     }
post-auth {
             update {
                     description := "Authenticated at %S"
             }
     }
```

Получилось подключить клиента через тест

```
radtest 00:18:DE:9D:45:98 Accept localhost 10 testing123
Sending Access-Request Id 130 from 0.0.0.0:33563 to 127.0.0.1:1812
    User-Name = '00:18:DE:9D:45:98'
    User-Password = 'Accept'
    NAS-IP-Address = 10.0.1.154
    NAS-Port = 10
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
Received Access-Accept Id 130 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:33563     length 20
```

Запись в лдап этого клиента:

```
description: Authenticated at 2016-06-09 16:19:45
objectclass: account
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: top
objectclass: radiusprofile
radiusframedipaddress: 192.168.88.27
radiusnasipaddress: 10.13.0.70
uid: 00:18:DE:9D:45:98
userpassword: Accept
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как создать запись в LDAP для NAS и какие атрибуты добавить в записи LDAP для клиентов, чтоб они начали получать ip от радиуса. Буду рад вашим дополнениям и поучениям. А также рабочим конфигам.